# Fastest Count of Row Dependent Date Ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set that looks like this (End_Time is 7 hours after Start_Time):

```
        Value               Start_Time              End_Time
1         A            2014-10-14 05:00:00    2014-10-14 12:00:00
2         A            2014-10-14 08:00:00    2014-10-14 15:00:00
3         A            2014-10-14 14:00:00    2014-10-14 21:00:00
4         A            2014-10-14 06:00:00    2014-10-14 13:00:00
5         B            2014-10-14 05:00:00    2014-10-14 12:00:00
6         B            2014-10-14 06:00:00    2014-10-14 13:00:00
```

I want to add a new column that counts the number of rows with the same Value with a Start_Time within the Start_Time and End_Time of that row. The result would look like this:

```
        Value               Start_Time              End_Time             Count          
1         A            2014-10-14 05:00:00    2014-10-14 12:00:00          2
2         A            2014-10-14 08:00:00    2014-10-14 15:00:00          1
3         A            2014-10-14 14:00:00    2014-10-14 21:00:00          0
4         A            2014-10-14 06:00:00    2014-10-14 13:00:00          2
5         B            2014-10-14 05:00:00    2014-10-14 12:00:00          1
6         B            2014-10-14 06:00:00    2014-10-14 13:00:00          0
```

Currently I have:

```
for i in range(0, len(df['Value'])):
    df['Count'][i] = df[(df['Start_Time'] >= df['Start_Time'][i]) & (df['Start_Time'] <= df['End_Time'][i]) & (df['Value'] == df['Value'][i])].shape[0]
```

I have a large number of rows and this turns out to be very slow and currently includes itself in the count so that every row needs to be subtracted by 1.

Is there a faster way to do this calculation?

Thanks!

Comment: can't you do a  groupby on the start time and then look at the length of the groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the only way you can achieve this quickly is if `Start_Time` increases. You could dispatch some complexity at insertion time by keeping ordered rows. With a sorted list of rows, testing if the following ones are within `[Start_Time, End_Time]` is easy, since as soon as you get an element which is not in the bound you'll know the following elements won't be either.

If you can't keep a sorted list at insertion, then I think there is no more efficient way than to sort the list.